# Call to a member function store() on null , al momento de querer subir una imagen por laravel/vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, fileupload

estoy trabajando en mi proyecto de laravel/vuejs pero me sale este error al momento de querer actualizar la ruta de la imagen:

Este es mi método en el controlador ya esta creado el modelo y todo si me modifica los atributos menos la imagen que deseo que se guarde en la base de datos alguien me pueda ayudar a resolver este problema:

```
public function actualizarcambiosgeneral(Request $request)
    {
        //if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
        $usuarios = Auth::user();
        $usuarios->idrol = $request->idrol;
        $usuarios->nombre = $request->nombre;
        $usuarios->apellido = $request->apellido;
        $usuarios->telefono = $request->telefono;
        $usuarios->direccion = $request->direccion;
        $usuarios->usuario = $request->usuario;
        $usuarios->estado = '1';
        $usuarios->usuario = $request->usuario;
        $usuarios->ruta=$request->file('ruta')->store('public');   
        $usuarios->save();
        return [
     
          'usuarios' => $usuarios
        ];
    }
```

este es mi archivo vuejs desde la parte de forulario:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="row">
                 <div class="media">
                      <figure>
                      <img  class="rounded mr-75" :src="Imagen" alt="Imagen de Pefil" height="64" width="64">
                    </figure>
                    <div class="media-body mt-75">
                    <div class="col-12 px-0 d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-start">
                    
                    <input type="file" id="ruta" @change="obtenerimagen" ref="upload" name="ruta">
                   
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-muted ml-75 mt-50"><small>Permitido JPG, GIF or PNG. tamaño maximo
                   de
                  1MB</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr>

              <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="controls">
              
              <label for="account-username">Nombre</label>
              <div v-if="!userg.nombre">
              <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid"  placeholder="Escriba sus nombres" v-model="userg.nombre" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)">
              </div>
              <div v-else>
                <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid"  placeholder="Escriba sus nombres" v-model="userg.nombre" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
        <label for="account-name">Apellido</label>
        <div v-if="!userg.apellido">
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" placeholder="Escriba sus apellidos" v-model="userg.apellido" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)">
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid" placeholder="Escriba sus apellidos" v-model="userg.apellido" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)">
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="controls">
      <label for="account-e-mail">Telefono</label>
      <div v-if="userg.telefono.length < 7 || userg.telefono.length > 7  || !userg.telefono">
      <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid"  placeholder="Escriba su telefono" v-model="userg.telefono" @keypress="restrictChars($event)">
      </div>
      <div v-else>
      <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid"  placeholder="Escriba su telefono" v-model="userg.telefono" @keypress="restrictChars($event)">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-12">
       <div class="form-group">
       <div class="controls">  
       <label for="account-company">Dirección</label>
       <div v-if="!userg.direccion">
       <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid"  placeholder="Escriba su dirección de domicilio" v-model="userg.direccion">
       </div>
       <div v-else>
       <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid"  placeholder="Escriba su dirección de domicilio" v-model="userg.direccion">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12">
       <div class="form-group">
       <div class="controls">  
       <label for="account-company">Nombre de Usuario</label>
       <div v-if="!userg.usuario">
       <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid"  placeholder="Escriba su nombre de usuario" v-model="userg.usuario">
       </div>
       <div v-else>
       <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid"  placeholder="Escriba su nombre de usuario" v-model="userg.usuario">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-end">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-sm-1 mb-1 mb-sm-0" :disabled="validarCambiosGeneral" @click="actualizargeneral()"  >Guardar Cambios</button>

       </div>
       </div>

      </form>
```

y este es mi script aqui ya cargo la imagen y mediante
un método actualizar con axios trato de actualizar los datos de
mi tabla, ayudenme como hago esto por favor :

---

```
<script>
 

  export default {
  data(){
  return{
    general:[],
    listado:0,
    nombre:'',
    apellido:'',
    telefono:'',
    direccion:'',
    usuario:'',
    idusuario:0,
    idrol:0,
    password:'',
    rpassword:'',
    ruta:'',
    errorPass : 0,
    errorMostrarMsjPassword : [],
    imagenMiniatura:''
  }
  },
 

  computed:{
  Imagen(){
  return this.imagenMiniatura; 
  },
  
  validarCambiosGeneral(){
  return !this.general[0].nombre || !this.general[0].apellido || 
  !this.general[0].telefono || this.general[0].telefono.length <7 || 
  this.general[0].telefono.length > 7 || !this.general[0].direccion || 
  !this.general[0].usuario;
  }
  },
  methods : {

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------
  obtenerimagen(e){
  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  if (!files.length)
  return;
  this.cargarImagen(files[0]);
  },

  cargarImagen(file){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var vm = this;

  reader.onload = (e) => {
      vm.general[0].ruta = e.target.result;
      vm.imagenMiniatura = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  },  

   actualizargeneral(){
    let me = this;
    axios.put('/usuario/actualizarcambiosgeneral',{
      'idrol': this.general[0].idrol,
      'nombre': this.general[0].nombre,
      'apellido': this.general[0].apellido,
      'telefono': this.general[0].telefono,
      'direccion': this.general[0].direccion,
      'usuario': this.general[0].usuario,
      'ruta': this.general[0].ruta,
      'id': this.general[0].id
    }).then(function (response) {
      document.querySelector('#navbar-username').innerText = me.general[0].nombre + " " + me.general[0].apellido;
      swal(
        'Actualizado!',
        'El registro se ha actualizado de forma exitosa.',
        'success'
      )
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }); 
  },

   },
   mounted() {
  this.listargeneral();
   }
   }
  </script>
```

Por favor alguien me especifique en que estoy fallando por favor

Comment: Dónde quedó el error?

Comment: Parece que `$request->file('ruta')` tiene valor `null`... Si el campo es requerido, te sugiero que hagas una validación, si no, agrega un `if ($request->hasFile('ruta'))` antes de intentar guardar el archivo al disco,

Comment: pueden revisar de nuevo y darme su opinion ? porque me da un valor null no entiendo

Comment: Si no hay archivo enviado el valor de ruta seria nulo, tambien puede ser que el archivo sea mas grande del limite de envio (chequear en php.ini `upload_max_filesize` y `post_max_size`)

Comment: Nunca veo que guardes la imagen en una variable

Comment: otra cosa ese metodo o esa forma para subir los datos con imagenes o archivos no va, es mas simple con FormData

Comment: me ayudas con un ejemplo, la verdad que soy nuevo en laravel con vuejs y tome un curso, pero justamente no enseñaron a subir imágenes a la base de datos

Comment: ayudame siendo mas explicito como lo podría ser, primero como lo estoy haciendo en el controlador esta bien o mal?, y luego en el archivo vuejs como lo podría hacer ayudame por favor